# Comparison of results of monte carlo simulations

Tags: monte-carlo

I am doing monte carlo simulations. In the first run the experiment is repeated e.g. 10000 times. The result looks like x+/-y, y is the relative error. Next, I change a part of the experiment and run again for e.g. 10000 times and have the result u+/-v, v the relative error.

It is possible that the difference between x and u is small and also there is the relative error. How can I assess this difference with respect to the relative errors?

Example:
First result: 91.6 +/- 9.84
Second result: 95.12 +/- 12.33
Is there a “real” difference in the results or is it just something within the errors?
Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks Ulrich

Comment: Is $\pm y$ the error in the estimate of the mean, or do most/all of the $10000$ values fall in that interval?

Answer (score 0):

A simple strategy is assume a normal distribution for your MC results. Please check if that applies to you, lot's of practical MC applications (at least my own experience) assume normal or log-normal distribution.

Now, you have your assumed distribution and all the individual recorded values. What's stopping you from something like t-test?